# Unable to install Cocoapods in macOS Monterey Version 12.0 Beta - Xcode 13.0(13A233)

Tags: ios, flutter, cocoapods, xcode13, macos-monterey

unable to install Cocoapods in MacOS 12.0 Beta and Xcode Version 13.0

here is terminal output for **sudo gem install cocoapods**

userName@users-Mac-mini ~ % sudo gem install cocoapods
Password:
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing cocoapods:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4/ext/ffi_c
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby -I /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20211006-2973-16tlcws.rb extconf.rb
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--without-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
--with-ffi_c-dir
--without-ffi_c-dir
--with-ffi_c-include
--without-ffi_c-include=${ffi_c-dir}/include
--with-ffi_c-lib
--without-ffi_c-lib=${ffi_c-dir}/lib
--enable-system-libffi
--disable-system-libffi
--with-libffi-config
--without-libffi-config
--with-pkg-config
--without-pkg-config
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:467:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError) You have to install development tools first. from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:546:in` block in try_link0'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tmpdir.rb:93:in `mktmpdir' from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:543:in` try_link0'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:570:in `try_link' from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:672:in` try_ldflags'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:1832:in `pkg_config' from extconf.rb:9:in` system_libffi_usable?'
from extconf.rb:42:in `'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/extensions/universal-darwin-21/2.6.0/ffi-1.15.4/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.4 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/extensions/universal-darwin-21/2.6.0/ffi-1.15.4/gem_make.out

Comment: To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log ❗️

Comment: checked it. but didn't get what should i do to resolve this issue :( /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX11.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/ruby.h:24:10: fatal error: 'ruby/config.h' file not found
#include "ruby/config.h"

Comment: Are you trying this on a fresh installation of macOS 12? Did you try to reinstall ruby?

Comment: Yes i have tried to Install / update Ruby as well. but no luck :/

Comment: did you find a way to solve this? I have the same issue with the released version of Monterey

Comment: @SebastiánCastro  not yet

Comment: @ShreeSoftech di you try homebrew, I used that and fixed my problem. If that works let me know and I put it as an answer for future questions

Comment: Today, I've updated MacOs Monterey, and have the same issue as you. So Can you help me ?

Comment: Do not install gems into the System Ruby! Use rbenv.

Answer (score 17):

I had the same problem while working through a Udemy course.  When I looked through the Q&A section there I found this little gem [no pun intended].

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods -v 1.8.4
```

This worked like a champ and installed with no issue.

But then I realized it was an outdated version and tried the

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

again.  I still had the same problem.

Then I went with Homebrew and used

```
brew install cocoapods
```

Hey... what do you know, it works.  Installed the latest and greatest stable version [v 1.11.2_1]

Comment: cocoapods -v 1.8.4 this worked but for some flutter projects with SDK 2.0 + , cocoapods version needs to be updated.

Comment: Only this line worked for me - sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods -v 1.8.4

Comment: worked on macOS 12.6.2 Xcode 14.2 - just used `brew install cocoapods`. After this, it's better to update `~/.zshrc` with:
if [ -d "/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin" ]; then
  export PATH=/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH
  export PATH=`gem environment gemdir`/bin:$PATH
fi

Answer (score 10):

If you installed cococoapods with gem, uninstall it:

```
gem uninstall cocoapods
```

Then install it with homebrew

```
brew install cocoapods
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

I have MacBook Pro with M1 chip and it worked by running the following commands

```
sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi
cd ios
arch -x86_64 pod install
```

Comment: Thanks but issue is on Intel Chip and not M1 sir

Comment: This solved my problem on M1 after updating to the Monterey system. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In my case this was caused because a older version of Xcode was being used for command line tools (Xcode 12.5.1). You can see which Xcode is being used by running this in Terminal:

`$ xcode-select --print-path`

macOS Monterey does not officially support Xcode versions older than 13.0 so I had to switch the Xcode version with:

`$ sudo xcode-select -switch <path/to/Xcode13>Xcode.app`

After switching the command line tools to Xcode 13 I was able to install CocoaPods successfully.

[Source for xcode-select switch command](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2339/_index.html)

Comment: This fixed it for me, and I suspect this is the correct answer. This can also be set directly from Xcode's UI @ Preferences -> Locations -> Command Line Tools.

Answer (score -1):

For me, it was HomeBrew that solved the issue. Uninstalled cocoapods and installed again trough HomeBrew. If you still have issues try to install the ffi library first, that could help too.

BTW, in my case was Monterey 12.0.1 not the beta, but it should be the same issue.