# Problem installing Cocoapods on older iMac running macOS 12.7.3

Tags: swift, ruby, cocoapods, macos-monterey

I'm a bit of a newbie, so please bear with me. :|

```
                                 ***************
```

1. I'm trying to add a pod to a Swift app I'm building in Xcode.
2. When I tried to install Cocoapods it threw a bunch of errors **(see below)**.

   ```
                                 ***************
   ```

$ sudo gem install cocoapods

Fetching ruby-macho-2.5.1.gem
Fetching escape-0.0.4.gem
Fetching nap-1.1.0.gem
Fetching fourflusher-2.3.1.gem
Fetching colored2-3.1.2.gem
Fetching addressable-2.8.6.gem
Fetching gh_inspector-1.1.3.gem
Fetching public_suffix-4.0.7.gem
Fetching rexml-3.2.6.gem
Fetching nanaimo-0.3.0.gem
Fetching claide-1.1.0.gem
Fetching atomos-0.1.3.gem
Fetching xcodeproj-1.24.0.gem
Fetching molinillo-0.8.0.gem
Fetching cocoapods-try-1.2.0.gem
Fetching netrc-0.11.0.gem
Fetching cocoapods-trunk-1.6.0.gem
Fetching cocoapods-search-1.0.1.gem
Fetching cocoapods-plugins-1.0.0.gem
Fetching cocoapods-downloader-2.1.gem
Fetching cocoapods-deintegrate-1.0.5.gem
Fetching ffi-1.16.3.gem
Fetching ethon-0.16.0.gem
Fetching typhoeus-1.4.1.gem
Fetching concurrent-ruby-1.2.3.gem
Fetching httpclient-2.8.3.gem
Fetching algoliasearch-1.27.5.gem
Fetching fuzzy_match-2.0.4.gem
Fetching ruby2_keywords-0.0.5.gem
Fetching drb-2.2.0.gem
Fetching base64-0.2.0.gem
Fetching connection_pool-2.4.1.gem
Fetching tzinfo-2.0.6.gem
Fetching i18n-1.14.1.gem
Fetching activesupport-7.1.3.gem
Fetching cocoapods-core-1.15.0.gem
Fetching cocoapods-1.15.0.gem
Successfully installed public_suffix-4.0.7
Successfully installed addressable-2.8.6
Successfully installed ruby-macho-2.5.1
Successfully installed nap-1.1.0
Successfully installed gh_inspector-1.1.3
Successfully installed fourflusher-2.3.1
Successfully installed escape-0.0.4
Successfully installed colored2-3.1.2
Successfully installed rexml-3.2.6
Successfully installed nanaimo-0.3.0
Successfully installed claide-1.1.0
Successfully installed atomos-0.1.3
Successfully installed xcodeproj-1.24.0
Successfully installed molinillo-0.8.0
Successfully installed cocoapods-try-1.2.0
Successfully installed netrc-0.11.0
Successfully installed cocoapods-trunk-1.6.0
Successfully installed cocoapods-search-1.0.1
Successfully installed cocoapods-plugins-1.0.0
Successfully installed cocoapods-downloader-2.1
Successfully installed cocoapods-deintegrate-1.0.5
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing cocoapods:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.16.3/ext/ffi_c
```

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby -I /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20240202-1849-nov6jr.rb extconf.rb
checking for ffi.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--without-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
--with-ffi_c-dir
--without-ffi_c-dir
--with-ffi_c-include
--without-ffi_c-include=${ffi_c-dir}/include
--with-ffi_c-lib
--without-ffi_c-lib=${ffi_c-dir}/lib
--enable-debug
--disable-debug
--enable-system-libffi
--disable-system-libffi
--with-libffi-config
--without-libffi-config
--with-pkg-config
--without-pkg-config
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:467:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError) You have to install development tools first. from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:585:in` block in try_compile'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:534:in `with_werror' from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:585:in` try_compile'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:1109:in `block in have_header' from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:959:in` block in checking_for'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:361:in `block (2 levels) in postpone' from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:331:in` open'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:361:in `block in postpone' from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:331:in` open'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:357:in `postpone' from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:958:in` checking_for'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:1108:in `have_header' from extconf.rb:10:in` system_libffi_usable?'
from extconf.rb:46:in `'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/extensions/universal-darwin-21/2.6.0/ffi-1.16.3/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.16.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/extensions/universal-darwin-21/2.6.0/ffi-1.16.3/gem_make.out

```
                                 ***************
```

3. Usually this happens because I'm running a fairly old macOS version (my iMac is so old it can no longer update beyond macOS 12) so I just install older versions of software. But as I'm a bit new to code, I don't really know how to fix this one.
4. It looks like I'm running Ruby 2.6.0, which is too old to upgrade to the latest version of Ruby.
5. I tried to upgrade Ruby gems **(see below)** per instructions I found somewhere but can't find again (I trawled through loads of threads but everything else looked far too advanced for my current level).
6. I reckon the latest version of Cocoapods is incompatible with Ruby 2.6.0 so I need to either find and install an older version of Cocoapods, or somehow upgrade my Ruby.
7. I'd prefer to avoid adding a huge amount of workarounds, codes, plugins, etc. to an already declining iMac if possible.
8. Please please help this wannabe coder with your simplest and old-iMac-friendliest suggestions. Thank you.

   ```
                                 ***************
   ```

$ sudo gem update --system

Updating rubygems-update
Fetching rubygems-update-3.5.5.gem
ERROR:  Error installing rubygems-update:
There are no versions of rubygems-update (= 3.5.5) compatible with your Ruby & RubyGems
rubygems-update requires Ruby version >= 3.0.0. The current ruby version is 2.6.10.210.
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
undefined method `version' for nil:NilClass

```
                                 ***************
```

Comment: Try with homebrew?

Comment: I don't really know enough about homebrew yet. I guess I'm going to have to put that on my to-learn list. :) I was hoping for a quick fix, tbh.

Comment: Just found this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69460048/23278514
Could it be that simple? I.e. simply using "brew install cocoapods"?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so here's an answer / update / new cry for help...

After the advice, "Try with homebrew?" I found this question/answer:
[Unable to install Cocoapods in macOS Monterey Version 12.0 Beta - Xcode 13.0(13A233)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69460048/23278514)

Which basically suggests the solution is to simply enter:
$ homebrew install cocoapods

So I tried that. And it kinda worked. So... partial answer received I guess (and therefore posted here for other Monterey users to find more easily).

However...

I now need help with the next problem:

```
                           ************
```

Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
Could not symlink bin/xcodeproj
Target /usr/local/bin/xcodeproj
already exists. You may want to remove it:
rm '/usr/local/bin/xcodeproj'

To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:
brew link --overwrite cocoapods

To list all files that would be deleted:
brew link --overwrite --dry-run cocoapods

Possible conflicting files are:
/usr/local/bin/xcodeproj
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.15.0: 13,736 files, 28.8MB
==> Running `brew cleanup cocoapods`...
Pruned 12 symbolic links and 8 directories from /usr/local

```
                           ************
```

Comment: Hi, if you have a new question you should create a new post